# why my vuforia mid- air app is not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am currently using Unity 2020.1.15f and Vuforia 9.6.3 SDK to create an augmented reality app that showcases 3D objects in mid-air. This setup was working well in the past, but recently I encountered an issue where the 3D objects are no longer appearing when I open the app and touch the screen. To address this problem, I updated Unity to version 2022.3.8 and also upgraded the Vuforia SDK to version 10.18, but the issue persists. after upgrade both unity and vuforia sdk the mid air is not working in unity editor.

Key Information:

Unity version: 2020.1.15f (previously) and 2022.3.8 (current).
Vuforia SDK version: 9.6.3 (previously) and 10.18 (current).
The desired behavior is to have 3D objects appear in mid-air when the app is opened and the screen is touched, but this is not happening.

Any help or suggestions for troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the same problem with the Vuforia Unity sample? If you see the same problem there you should file a bug here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine, otherwise you can try to compare your setup against the sample.

Comment: In addition to other suggestions, please be aware that not all devices support mid-air tracking (aka device tracker). You can review our recommended devices article for more guidance: https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/recommended-devices

Comment: @Dave D ,Previously, I built an APK with Unity 2020.1.15f and Vuforia 9.6.3 SDK, and it was working fine on my mobile (Realme Narzo 30) as well as other devices. However, in recent days, the mid-air functionality has stopped working. The camera opens, but when I touch the screen, the object is supposed to appear, but it is not functioning as expected.

Comment: @emay,I've tried two scenarios. In the first scenario, the combination of Unity 2020.1.15f and Vuforia 9.6.3  mid air works fine in the editor, but it's not working on Android devices. In the second scenario, with Unity 2022.3.8f and Vuforia 10.18, it's not working in the editor as well.

Comment: @SivaT I don't see where the Realme Narzo 30 supports device tracking via ARCore (see https://developers.google.com/ar/devices). Please try with another device that supports ARCore. I cannot explain why mid air would work in the Unity Editor with 9.6.3, but I don't believe there is an expectation that it would work in the Editor with 10.18 considering we don't support mid air tracking with USB cameras.